# How to programmatically adjust the disable directive in the mod_jk load balancer configuration?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, mod-jk

We have a setup where we have one httpd (apache) with mod_jk talking in a load balance setup to three tomcat servers.  We have to recycle each tomcat instance envery three hours.  So tomcat1 will restart at 1, and tomcat2 at 2 and ... until tomcat1 recycles again at 4.

We want to configure a script or a type of program to disable the worker node that is going through a recylce to minimize session errors at the user using our application.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris thanks or your answer. I am sure it will work, but I wanted to trigger the change at run time, even though the graceful restart is very similar.  I was able to accomplish my describe task the following way.

In your httpd.conf file you should add the following lines to enable the jkmanager for mod_jk module.

```
<Location /jkmanager/>
JkMount jkstatus
order deny,allow
allow from <your ip address>
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all
</Location>

<IfModule mod_jk.c>
...
JkMount  /jkmanager/* jkstatus
...
</IfModule>
```

The changes on the "workers.properties" file are:

```
 worker.list=router,tomcat1,tomcat2,...,tomcatn,jkstatus
 worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

After these changes are done, you are able to see the jkmanager by typing your url followed by /jkmanager/ at the end.  You should get something similar to the following picture.

[image: jkmanager screenshot]

In order to disable workers at run time just run the following URLs against the jkmanger.  You can even read status in an xml format.

To disable tomcat1 just hit:

```
http://your.web.server/jkmanager/?cmd=update&w=router&opt=256&from=list&att=vwa&val0=1&val1=0&val2=0
```

To enable tomcat1 back hit:

```
http://your.web.server/jkmanager/?cmd=update&w=router&opt=256&from=list&att=vwa&val0=0&val1=0&val2=0
```

I posted a complete article in my blog explaining the setup in case someone needs to know.

[Cloud Computing Blog](http://www.kiragiannis.com/cloud-computing/growing-and-shrinking-tomcat-workers-in-the-cloud/)

Comment: hi I am doing the same but I am not be able to get the above screen. Other is working well. What to do??

Comment: The Cloud Computing Blog link is broken too. No idea where it's suppose to be going, so couldn't find a replica.

Answer (score 2):

mod_jk re-reads workers.properties on an "apachectl graceful", so you if your workers.properties looks like this:

```
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balanced_workers=tomcat1, tomcat2, tomcat3

...
```

You could just write a script which replaces the balanced_workers list with the ones you want, and then graceful's apache

*Update* here's a script to do just that, which I cobbled together from some bits I had lying around. I wouldn't suggest using it in production, but it might give you some ideas for your own version.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set some paths
WORKERS_PROPERTIES="./workers.properties"
APACHECTL="/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"

# what does the loadbalancer config line look like?
WORKER_LINE_START="worker.loadbalancer.balanced_workers="
# full list of workers
ALL_WORKERS="tomcat1 tomcat2 tomcat3"

# first command line arg is the worker to remove. 
remove=$1

# build up the new line listing the active workers
worker_line=$WORKER_LINE_START
sep=""
for worker in $ALL_WORKERS
do
  if [ ${remove} != ${worker} ]
  then
     worker_line="${worker_line}$sep $worker"
     sep=","
  fi
done

# sed hackery to replace the current line with the one we just built.
# needs gnu sed (or another one that supports in-place editing)
sed -i.bak "s/^$WORKER_LINE_START.*$/$worker_line/" $WORKERS_PROPERTIES

# restart apache
$APACHECTL graceful
```

Answer (score 2):

gkiragiannis, you answer was interesting, but doesn't seem to work for me. I wanted to only disable one of my subworkers at a time.

Lets assume we are working with the 'agent-lb' load balancer.

To view the worker status using this url:

```
server-name/jkmanager/?cmd=list&w=agent-lb
```

To disable the 'agent-n1' sub worker use this url:

```
server-name/jkmanager/?cmd=update&w=agent-lb&sw=agent-n1&vwa=1
```

To ensure that the worker is disabled wait for the redirect to the worker status page, and look in the 'Act' field for the sub worker, 'agent-n1'

To enable the 'agent-n1' sub worker use this url:

```
server-name/jkmanager/?cmd=update&w=agent-lb&sw=agent-n1&vwa=0
```