# tomcat-apache-mod_jk fine tune apache server timeouts to allow restart tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I have apache http server in front of tomcat 7.0. I use mod_jk apache module to send an incoming http request to the servlet container. 
I would like to setup the apache server such that if I restart the tomcat server and it comes back within X seconds, then apache server should not produce any error for that request. I am wondering how to set the parameters in apache server so that it can hold the incoming http request for X seconds while tomcat restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible to do this with the jkmanager .

see this topic :

[How to programmatically adjust the disable directive in the mod_jk load balancer configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766891/how-to-programmatically-adjust-the-disable-directive-in-the-mod-jk-load-balancer/769538#769538)

bests regards